# How can i enable smart invert in iOS? (Objective C and cydia jailbreak app)

Tags: objective-c, cydia, cydia-substrate

I know turning stock accessibility options in an app is not possible but it’s a Cydia app, meaning it has root access so I’m wondering if it’s possible to force enable the dark mode, or else how can i invert the colors and the UILabel ?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any way to do this?